# Function to unit csv files in clipboard

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv

I have this simple function that unit csv files to clipboard in a GUI with tkinter, sometimes just have 1 or 2 files to upload, so how i can make this code that dont give me an error when some csv file doesnt exist?

```
def load1():
    f1 = askopenfilenames(filetypes=(('GZ File', '*.gz'), ('All Files', '*.*')))
    data1 = pd.read_csv(f1[0], sep=';', compression='gzip', error_bad_lines=False)
    data2 = pd.read_csv(f1[1], sep=';', compression='gzip', error_bad_lines=False)
    data3 = pd.read_csv(f1[2], sep=';', compression='gzip', error_bad_lines=False)
    pd.concat([data1,data2,data3], sort=False).to_clipboard(sep=',', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you use `for`-loop if you have many elements?

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I don't understand why don't you use `for`-loop if you have many elements - it is basic rule.

```
f1 = askopenfilenames(filetypes=(('GZ File', '*.gz'), ('All Files', '*.*')))

all_data = []

for name in f1:
    data = pd.read_csv(name, sep=';', compression='gzip', error_bad_lines=False)
    all_data.append(data)

pd.concat(all_data, sort=False).to_clipboard(sep=',', index=False)
```

Comment: thank u so much, thats works for me, im a begginer in this!